# Pandas: Filtering pivot table rows where count is fewer than specified value

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas pivot table that looks a little like this:

```
C             bar       foo
A     B                    
one   A -1.154627 -0.243234
three A -1.327977  0.243234
      B  1.327977 -0.079051
      C -0.832506  1.327977  
two   A  1.327977 -0.128534
      B  0.835120  1.327977
      C  1.327977  0.838040
```

I'd like to be able to filter out rows where column A has fewer than 2 rows in column B, so that the table above would filter A = one:

```
C             bar       foo
A     B                    
three A -1.327977  0.243234
      B  1.327977 -0.079051
      C -0.832506  1.327977  
two   A  1.327977 -0.128534
      B  0.835120  1.327977
      C  1.327977  0.838040
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In one line:

```
In [64]: df[df.groupby(level=0).bar.transform(lambda x: len(x) >= 2).astype('bool')]
Out[64]: 
              bar       foo
two   A  0.944908  0.701687
      B -0.204075  0.713141
      C  0.730844 -0.022302
three A  1.263489 -1.382653
      B  0.124444  0.907667
      C -2.407691 -0.773040
```

In the upcoming release of pandas (11.1), the new [`filter` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#filtration) achieves this faster and more intuitively:

```
In [65]: df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x['bar']) >= 2)
Out[65]: 
              bar       foo
three A  1.263489 -1.382653
      B  0.124444  0.907667
      C -2.407691 -0.773040
two   A  0.944908  0.701687
      B -0.204075  0.713141
      C  0.730844 -0.022302
```

Comment: get the word on ``filter`` out there!

Comment: The people need to know. Amen!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to groupby the 'A', and look at those groups over size 3:

```
In [11]: g = df1.groupby(level='A')

In [12]: g.size()
Out[12]:
A
one      1
three    3
two      3
dtype: int64

In [13]: size = g.size()

In [13]: big_size = size[size>=3]

In [14]: big_size
Out[14]:
A
three    3
two      3
dtype: int64
```

Then you can see which rows have "good" 'A' values, and slice by these:

```
In [15]: good_A = df1.index.get_level_values('A').isin(big_size.index)

In [16]: good_A
Out[16]: array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [17]: df1[good_A]
Out[17]:
              bar       foo
A     B
three A -1.327977  0.243234
      B  1.327977 -0.079051
      C -0.832506  1.327977
two   A  1.327977 -0.128534
      B  0.835120  1.327977
      C  1.327977  0.838040
```

Comment: [15] seems a bit hacky... (!)

Comment: I think this is an original solution for the filtering-by-group problem. My answer uses one by Wes, shorter but maybe less readable. Once 11.1 is out, [``filter``](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#filtration) will unquestionably be the way to go.