# Filtering a count column in a Pandas Pivot Table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

With a pandas dataframe, 
I do this:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, index='month', columns = ['metro'], aggfunc = {  'metro' : 'count' }  )
```

How to report only those columns where any count in that column exceeds some cutoff number, let's say 10?

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109419/pandas-filtering-pivot-table-rows-where-count-is-fewer-than-specified-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over columns and drop ones not meeting your criteria:

```
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, index='month', columns = ['metro'], aggfunc = {  'metro' : 'count' }  )

for col in pvt.columns:
    if not any(pvt[col] > 10):
        pvt.drop(col,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Note df here refers to the result of the pivot table i gave in the question.

Comment: Yes, thank you - I will edit my answer a bit to make it (hopefully) more clear